# Error when importing torch_geometric in Python 3.9.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, pytorch-geometric

I'm trying to install torch_geometric in a conda environment but I'm getting the following werror whenever I try to:

```
import torch_geometric
```

Error:

```
OSError: dlopen(/Users/psanchez/miniconda3/envs/playbook/lib/python3.9/site-packages/libpyg.so, 0x0006): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/python@3.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/Python
  Referenced from: <95F9BBA5-21FB-3EA5-9028-172B745E6ABA> /Users/psanchez/miniconda3/envs/playbook/lib/python3.9/site-packages/libpyg.so
  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/python@3.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/Python' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/opt/python@3.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/Python' (no such file), '/usr/local/opt/python@3.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/Python' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/Python' (no such file), '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/Python' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
```

This is how I installed the conda envrionment:

```
onda create --name playbook python=3.9.7  --no-default-packages
conda activate playbook

pip install torch==1.13.1 torchvision==0.14.1


pip install pyg-lib torch-scatter torch-sparse torch-cluster torch-spline-conv torch-geometric -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-1.13.0+cpu.html
```

Any idea how to solve this error?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well--I don't know *why* it wants Python 3.10 specifically. But I was able to resolve it by installing a global version Python 3.10:

https://www.python.org/downloads/macos/

This allows it to access Python 3.10 outside your virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you check your error message, on the line "Referenced from" you can see Python version 3.9 but on the line "Reason tried", you have Python version 3.10.

So i think you are using a Python environment 3.10 with Python 3.9 or the opposite. You should recreate your environment cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well.I used python3.7 it worked:

```
conda create -n pygeometric python=3.7

conda activate pygeometric

conda install pytorch torchvision -c pytorch

python -c "import torch; print(torch.__version__)"

conda install -y clang_osx-64 clangxx_osx-64 gfortran_osx-64

MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.9 CC=clang CXX=clang++

pip install torch_scatter

python -c "import torch_scatter; print(torch_scatter.__version__)"

pip install torch_sparse 

python -c "import torch_sparse; print(torch_sparse.__version__)"

pip install torch_cluster

python -c "import torch_cluster; print(torch_cluster.__version__)"

pip install torch-spline-conv

python -c "import torch_spline_conv;print(torch_spline_conv.__version__)"

pip install torch_geometric

python -c "import torch_geometric;print(torch_geometric.__version__)"
```